# Seeding an Entity Database with Related Tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I read through the other answers that I could find, but none of them helped me. I am quite new to .NET, Entity, C# etc. So I hope you'll forgive me. I am trying to create a "Seed" file and I get errors when I try to seed all the tables separately, when it's a related table. I am trying to see not only a child table, but a grandchild as well (hope that makes sense). For example here's what I was trying now due to a post I found:

```
context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(i => i.ProjectID, 
     new Project
     {
        ProjectID = 1,
        Title = "Project 1",
        ProjectDoc = new List<ProjectDoc>
            {
                new ProjectDoc { 
                     ProjectDocID = 1, ProjectID = 1, Content = "Doc Content", DocTitle = "Chapter 1", 
                        Comment = new List<Comment> 
                        {
                             new Comment { ProjectDocID = 1, CommentID = 1, Text = "Comment text" }
                        }
                     }
                  }
             }
        );
```

My Problem is with:

```
 Comment = **new** List<Comment>
```

That "new" is causing an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List....

I tried to Google that, but I didn't understand the jargon that I found. Help?

Comment: Can you please post your DbContext file?

Comment: why is there a problem with new List of comments and no problem with new list of Project docs, plus why are you specifying primary key values, they should be auto-generated and assigned from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not directly related to your issue you should simply not use `AddOrUpdate` for object graphs. The internal logic of the method doesn't check related objects so you may solve your issue and make it work but only Add part will will be functional. When you add, update or remove `ProjectDoc` or `Comment` the `Seed` method will not recognize the change. It only recognizes changes in `Project` instance directly.

Comment: Turns out I had other issues as well, after I did a better (hopefully) job understanding and using the "Fluent API" instead of  a required annotation I've made progress. Though it isn't working yet. Thanks for the response!